# filter last 24 hour data and collect data from SQL

Tags: php, sql

The following code seems to be not working for me, what went wrong.

```
$que = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE phone=9876543210 WHERE status=10 AND clickdate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
```

Intention was to collect data of users with the phone number 9876543210 and status=10, but only within last 24 hours from the table "people". "clickdate" is the date column  in database.

Comment: here's the hint `WHERE phone=9876543210 WHERE status=10`

Comment: @Kevin, is WHERE phone=9876543210  AND status=10 AND clickdate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)   
is this the correct format ?

Comment: @MalavikaP  ya format is correct now.

Comment: You should debug at the SQL level before bringing to PHP. Also, you should look at how to get error reporting for whichever driver you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `WHERE` in your query. Replace second `where` with `and`

```
SELECT * 
FROM people 
WHERE phone=9876543210 
AND status=10 
AND clickdate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```